# Mathematical Modeling of Route Optimization

Tags: computer-science, linear-programming, mathematical-modeling

Do any of you know how to come up with equations or mathematical way of representing these problems?

1) Finding probability of choosing number of routes
      (i) If n of routes less than 4, consider all routes
     (ii) else if n of routes is equal or more than 4, consider 40% of the n of
          routes (round up decimal point)

2) Randomly choose which routes to consider out of all possible routes (this is 
    for the case in which n of routes is more than or equal than 4)

3) Compare the chosen routes and take the route with lowest traveling time 
    as the best route

Basically, I need to come up with a mathematical model to this problem and I would appreciate it if anyone could come up with a logical way to do so. Thank you  :)

Comment: Do you have numbers associated with these problem statements.  Seems close to travelling salesman problem.  Could be a close variant of that and if possible please let us know the source of the problem

Comment: Yes, it is a type of TSP problem. Assuming that there are 7 possible routes in which 4 routes (A,B,C and D) are chosen randomly using a math function. The traveling time for these routes are as below: A = 4 min, B = 6 min, C = 2 min and D = 8 min. Initialize the first route as the initial best route. Now the problem is how to come up with a mathematical way of comparing these 4 routes so that the output will be the route with lowest traveling time.

Comment: What happened to the  traveling time of 3 other routes?  Why don't you make up some numbers ( I could do, but yours will be better with the problem in hand).

Comment: E = 1 min, F = 5 min, G = 4 min. The routes that are not chosen will not be considered. It will only be considered if it is chosen the next time a random choosing occur and the result will be updated (machine learning capability). Therefore, for this problem, the routes considered are ABCD only even though D has better traveling time.

Comment: Well as in your Question you are explicitly quoting probabilities i would reject the idea, but if it shouldn't necessary be solved by probability, Dijkstra'a algorithm would be my choice https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm!

Answer (score 0):

I have not understood completely what you want.  From what I have understood, here is a way you can achieve the task.

Create a non uniform distribution such as below.
[image]

Now for the part I,

Let n be the number of routes

Then $P(n<3) = \sum_{i=0}^{3} P(Z_i)$

Then $P(n>=4) = \sum_{i=0}^{Roundup(.4*n)} P(rand(Z_i))$

Part II,

The following code shall enable you to choose at random any four routes.

r = rand()

If r lies between $A_{i}<=r<=A_{i+1}$

Choose $Z_{i+1}$

Repeat three more times for i's not chosen before.

Then do a bubblesort on the choosen routes based on the traveling time and choose the lowest. (Bubblesort will arrange the routes based on the traveling time in an ascending or descending order).

For i = 1 To 6

For j = i To 7

If (Time(i) <= Time(j)) Then

Temp = Time(i)

Time(i) = Time(j)

Time(j) = Temp

End If

Next

Next